# How to add bonmin to pyomo solvers?

Tags: pyomo

I can use many solvers like ipopt in pyomo, however I have to use bonmin. 
When I try to use bonmin I get this;

WARNING: Failed to create solver with name 'bonmin': Failed to set executable     for solver asl. File with name=bonmin either does not exist or it is not     executable. To skip this validation, call set_executable with     validate=False.

Comment: you should make sure that `bonmin` is on your system path. When you open up a terminal (or command prompt) and type `bonmin`, what is the output?